# Is the cloud a group of datacenters?

Tags: server, cloud, backend, differentiation, docker-datacenter

Im working in a speech of internet energetic impact for my school and i fell in a question through my researchs:

Are the clouds simply a group of datacenters?

Everyone just talks about the differences between each other, and get to the point to be accepting that the data stored in the cloud will only be destroyed if the full internet end. But... In my deduction the data must have a physical storage "because internet is not magic" (no matter if its distributed storages or mono-storage). So, why not say the cloud is just a group of datacenters or servers?

Please be kind, im a student.

And thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

you are correct, the cloud is a group of data centers. but the affirmation " the data stored in the cloud will only be destroyed if the full internet end" could be true, because these data centers are distributes around the world, so the service will completely stop only if all the data centers stop at same time.

Hope it was useful, bye.

Comment: So its exactly what i was expecting. Thank you very much, it is really usefull to help me understand the subject correctly.